# How can I know the name of my iPhone programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone

I have connected two iPhones via bluetooth programmatically. Now I want to know the name of the device that I am connected to and the name of my device both programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your device's name:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
```

To get the other device's name:

```
[instanceOfGKSession displayNameForPeer:peerID];
```

And if you use `initWithSessionID:displayName:sessionMode:` to make the session, you can just use that display name as your device's name.

Programming Guide [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-SW1).

Answer (score 1):

for your device's name:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
```